# Find count of number of pairs in the list

Tags: python, list

I have list of numbers:

```
[5, 4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5,]
```

A pair of numbers is the same 2 numbers. For example, 5 occurs 4 times, so we have 2 pairs of 5s. In the list above I can say I have 5 pairs. I want the output to count how many pairs of numbers are in the list.

I tried this, but got stuck.

```
list = [5,4,3,4,2,1,3,5]
print(list)
temp = 0
new_list = []
for index,x in enumerate(list):
    elm_count = list.count(list[index])
    if new_list:
        for ind, y in enumerate(new_list):
            if list[index] == new_list[ind]:
                continue
                if not elm_count % 2:
                    occ_count = elm_count/2
                    temp += occ_count
                    new_list.append(list[index])
                    continue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler way to achieve this is using [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) with [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) as:

```
>>> my_list = [5, 4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5,3, 5, 3, 5,]

>>> sum(num//2 for num in Counter(my_list).values())
5
```

Here `Counter()` will generate a `dict` with number as *key* and count of occurrence of number in list as its value. Then I am iterating over its values and calculating the count of pairs for each number using *generator expression*, and doing summation on the count of all the pairs using `sum()`.

You can refer below documents for more details:

- [`collections.Counter()` document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)
- [`sum()` document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)